# Get list of all public tweets using New Twitter API 1.1 in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, ios7

I am having an app in which I want the public tweets from twitter in my iOS app.

I want something like shown below in the image.

[image]

`TWRequest` is deprecated, so I used the following code but it is not working:

```
NSURL *atweet = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=SrBachchan"];


 SLRequest *aRequest  = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                          requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                    URL:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=SrBachchan"
                                             parameters:nil];
   

[aRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
{
    NSString *output;
    NSLog(@"in handler block");
    if ([urlResponse statusCode]==200)
    {
        NSError *jsonParsingError= nil;
        NSDictionary *publictimeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
        
        output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status was: %li \nPublic Time Line: \n %@",(long)[urlResponse statusCode],publictimeline];
        
    }
    else
    {
       output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No Feed  HTTP response status was: %li \n ",(long)[urlResponse statusCode]];
    }
    
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displyreult:) withObject:output waitUntilDone:NO];
    
    
}];

  -(void)displyreult:(NSString *)text;
{
  _twittertwitte.text =@"";
  _twittertwitte.text =text;


}
```

I am stuck on this for quite a while. I searched a lot but couldn't find a solution.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

You should get in the habit of reading errors. In this case, [the URL you posted](https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=SrBachchan) returns this error:

```
{  
   "errors":[  
      {  
         "message":"The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.",
         "code":64
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is [the overview](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview) and [the full documentation for the API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1).

Here is [Twitter's blog post from 2 years ago](https://blog.twitter.com/2012/changes-coming-to-twitter-api) outlining the necessary changes.

Comment: I am sorry for that, as i have done this for the first time. 
But can you send me a demo?

Comment: No, but there are plenty tutorials online. https://www.google.com/search?q=iOS%20Twitter%201.1%20API&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: If you have a specific problem once you try, feel free to post a question here (although it's probably already been answered).